# 'ready to measure' or 'ready to be measured'?

Tags: grammar

I am writing a scientific paper. I have to talk about some physical quantity which can be easily measured.

The question is,

> The quantity is ready ***to measure***

or

> The quantity is ready ***to be measured***

Comment: Please post the full context of the sentence. I'm inclined to say "ready to be measured", but either could be correct depending on the specific sentence.

Comment: to be easily measured, can be easily measured, can be readily measured, to be measured readily, are the all I can say !

Answer (score 5):

The adjective [ready](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ready) does not have the meaning that you want. If you want to say that something can be done easily, you have to use the adverbal form [readily](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/readily). You can use it anywhere that you would use **easily**. Adverb positioning is quite flexible, but I would favour the first of these options:

> The parameter can readily be measured
>
> The parameter can be readily measured
>
> The parameter can be measured readily

**readily** is quite formal, so its usage is probably appropriate in a scientific paper: **easily** is much more widely used in everyday speech.

Comment: Nice answer of (what I thought to be) a confusing question. "The quantity is readily measurable" makes a lot more sense in the context of the question than either of the options the asker gave.